# Finding Curvature, is $K=\frac{|\vec{s}'(t) \times \vec{s}''(t)|}{||\vec{s}'(t)||^3}$ the right formula to use?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, curvature

In [this lesson](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/curvature/v/curvature-formula-part-5), Grant/Khan taught that $K=\frac{|\vec{s}'(t) \times \vec{s}''(t)}{||\vec{s}'(t)||^3}$:

[image] =[image]

If the formula is right, is it generalisable to all dimensions? I applied it to $\vec{s}(t)= (\cos t, \sin t, \frac{t}{5})$ to find the curvature function for the graph (a helix) and got the following:

1. first & second derivative of $\vec{s}(t)$:

$\vec{s}'(t)= \begin{bmatrix} -\sin t\\\cos t \\ \frac{1}{5}\end{bmatrix}$ , $\vec{s} ''(t) =\begin{bmatrix} - \cos t\\ -\sin t \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$

2. Cross the numerator, and divided it by the denominator:

$\frac{\frac{1}{5}(\sin t - \cos t t)+1}{\frac{26\sqrt{26}}{125}}$, which seem to be the wrong answer.

I've verified that the derivatives, cross product and the magnitude in the denominator is correct. What aim I missing here?

The right answer is simply a constant $K=\frac{25}{26}$ which makes sense. The only difference is that I followed the formula then normalized it at the end. But Grant normalized the numerator first.

Comment: The magnitude of numerator has not been taken. As far as I know, this formula is only for curves in $\mathbb{R^3}$ since otherwise cross product would go to determinant that requires square ($n\times n$) matrices. There is another characterization though using Riemannian connections, in which case curvature for curves in manifolds of any dimension are just magnitude of “g”-acceleration: $\kappa(t) = \big| \nabla_{\dot{\gamma(t)}}\dot{\gamma(t)}\big|_g$

Comment: You are right I did not take the magnitude. However, even after I normalized $\vec{s}'(t)$ and $\vec{s}''(t)$ to $||\vec{s}'(t)||$ (i.e. divide both of them by $||\vec{s}'(t)||$). After crossing them, I still get variables on my numerator(my workings: https://imgur.com/a/F54CkKq), do you know why? There seem to not be a way to solve it using this formula at all. To know it only works in 2D/3D, makes it even less meaningful.

Comment: Oh I see what happened, the cross should be a vector output.

Comment: Also, one should be consistent with the norm vertical bars, $|\cdot|$ vs. $||\cdot||$. Depending on context, both are used, but when used at the same time, the single bars are used for scalars.

Comment: You're absolutely right @KevinS , thanks for pointing it out. Went back and worked it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the numerator
$\vec{s}'(t)
\times
\vec{s} ''(t) 
=
\begin{bmatrix} -\sin t\\\cos t \\ \frac{1}{5}\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix} - \cos t\\ -\sin t \\ 0\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} \frac15 \sin t\\ -\frac15 \cos t \\ 1\end{bmatrix}
$
with norm $n=\sqrt{\frac{1}{25}+1}$

for the denominator, norm is $d=\sqrt{\frac{1}{25}+1}$

Finally curvature is
$$
k=\frac{n}{d^3}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{25}+1}=\frac{25}{26}$$

Comment: Got it so we cross, then find the magnitude of it, thank you! The formula is wrong and ought to be $K=\frac{||\vec{s}'(t) \times \vec{s}''(t)||}{||\vec{s}'(t)||^3}$